# The field ValidFrom must be a date (jQuery Unobtrusive Validation)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, validation, model-view-controller

I use MVC. jQuery send me the validation messege that the form must be a date even if my model is sending the right format. I ve decorated the fields in the model of these attributes:

```
   [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}")]
```

In the view I have:

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ValidFrom })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ValidFrom)
```

but without result. Any ideas how to fix the validation?

Comment: Can you show what your `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ValidFrom })` line renders to?

Comment: public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }

Comment: Sorry, I meant Could you show the the HTML rendered by that line?

Comment: can you show jquery validation code ?

Comment: <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field ValidFrom must be a date." data-val-required="The ValidFrom field is required." id="ValidFrom" name="ValidFrom" type="datetime" value="20.10.2015" />

Comment: Does `20.10.2015 01:00:00` validate?